# Where is default source fetch `fetchRequestForSourceEntityNamed:predicateString:` for `NSMigrationManager` defined?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

The default source fetch expression
`sourceExpression FETCH(FUNCTION($manager, "fetchRequestForSourceEntityNamed:predicateString:" , "MyEntity", "TRUEPREDICATE"), $manager.sourceContext, NO)` refers to `fetchRequestForSourceEntityNamed:predicateString:` method of `NSMigrationManager`.

But it is not defined anywhere, or at least I could not find it!

I want to override this method to return an array of *unique* items, preferably by calling the `super` method first and filtering later.

Can you point me to the default definition of this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an Apple private API.  There is no documentation available.  Give it an entity, [predicate string](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html), and test it thoroughly.  Of course, you can also pass it your own function instead of overriding.

Comment: I am passing my own function, but I’d rather call the original one instead of doing fetch myself. Because now it fails for some unknown reason when returning the result to the migration manager (“fetch is invalid”).

Comment: I've never seen "fetch is invalid", but it seems like it should be solveable :)

Comment: Here it is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306232/is-not-a-valid-nsfetchrequest