# '<...> is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I am using a custom source expression

```
NSExpression(format: "FETCH(FUNCTION($manager, \"customFetchRequestForSourceEntityNamed:predicateString:\" , \"\(mapping.sourceEntityName!)\", \"TRUEPREDICATE\"), $manager.sourceContext, NO)")
```

for mapping model.

The fetch is being executed normally within the custom method, but exception `'<...> is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'` is thrown somewhere later inside the `NSMigrationManager.migrateStore()` method.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected result type of this method is `NSFetchRequest`, not what the fetch returns.

The signature would be -

```swift
extension NSMigrationManager {

    @objc func customFetchRequest(forSourceEntityNamed entityName: String, predicateString: String) -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
```